# Do LocalChannel/LocalServerChannel serialize data written to them?

Tags: netty

I would like to use LocalChannel & LocalServerChannel to have an in-jvm link between a client and server.  I was wondering if i can pass objects unchanged via the channel between them without having to encode/decode them along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the objects without usual encoding/decoding, the message events are exchanged between paired channels directly.

Comment: Is there an example of this around?  Or is it at simple as the the message attached on messageReceived is the original object I sent through the channel?